# Regression SPSS : How to see which IV is the strongest predictor of my DV?

Tags: regression, spss

[image]

Hey all, I run Multiple Regression. How to see which IV is the strongest predictor of my DV? From SPSS Table.

My IVs
1. Attitude
2. SN
3. PBC

My Dvs
Intention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a multiple regression, the standardized coefficients (Beta) answer the question which of the independent variables have a greater effect on the dependent variable. Beta can be interpreted like the Pearson coefficient *r* on a scale -1 to 1. According to the table, the two independent variables AttitudesTotal and PBC_Total have similar magnitudes but opposite signs; in other words, they exhibit an inverse relationship. This suggests that they are equally "strong". However, determining which predictor (independent variable) is more important can only be determined in context using subject matter knowledge.

Comment: Sir, thank you for your help. You mentioned that 2 of my IVs (Attitudes and PBC) are equally "strong". And in order to determine which is which predictor (independent variable) is more important i need to determine in context using subject matter knowledge. Can I have some idea how to do this? I have the demographic background of the subjects. I am very sorry to trouble, and thank you so much.

Comment: If you describe your study in detail I may be able to help you. For example, what is the purpose of the study? Did you collect the data or where did it come from? Also describe each variable in detail, so that I know what they are.

Comment: The purpose of my study is To confirm the relationship between Attitude toward pornography, Subjective Norms (SN), Perceived Behavioral Control (PBC) and the Intention to stop pornography viewing.


I run multiple regression to determine the contributions of attitude towards pornography; subjective Norms (SN); Perceived Behavioural Control (PBC) to the prediction of intentions to stop pornography viewing among Malaysian Youths.

The data n=160, via online survey,  all subjects are currently pornography viewer. 110 Male &50 Female.

Comment: Attitude toward pornography = The degree of one’s favourable or unfavourable evaluation of the pornography watching could be either positive or negative.  

;SN = It is one’s perception and belief of social pressure from either parents, or friends in the viewing of pornography.

;PBC =  It is one’s perception of the ease or difficulty in the effort of reducing pornography viewing.
;Intention = The desire or motivation to stop pornography viewing.

Comment: I am no psychologist, but I would suggest that you perform a separate analysis for males and females. Perhaps it will take your analysis to the next step.